# MOSS: Approval Workflow: how to make the document readonly after it has been approved

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-2007

I am new to MOSS development and while I'm learning it I have a problem waiting to be solved.

We are using the standard approval workflow in one of our test sites just to get the feel of the approval workflow. We have the standard approval workflow in place and working but what has become more desirable is to have the document set to readonly mode after its approval.

What should be my approach to configure/implement this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom ItemUpdating event handler on the workflow task list - check the status of the task, and if it is Approved, get the Item object through the task workflow association and adjust permissions on the Item.

Answer (score 0):

Or you start a second workflow - depending on the approval workflow outcome. Create a SharePoint Designer Workflow using the custom activities to set the item permissions.

To set the item permissions download the [Useful Sharepoint Designer Custom Workflow Activities](http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Grant%20Permission%20on%20Item)

The advantage of this approach is, that you do not need to write code to create an Eventhandler.